# draw CGPaths to UIView then save view as Png

Tags: ios4, uiimage, drawing

In the drawrect function of a UIView I use CGContext to draw some shapes. This Works fine, I can see my shapes.
Now I'm trying to save what has been drawn on the view as a png on disk. I've read various docs / articles but nothing gets saved. Im testing on the simulator for ios 4.3.

**Edit 1**

I changed my code and uncommented the context part. I can save the png but it is blank.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    CGContextRef ctx= UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0, 0, 0, .5);
    CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, mutatablepath);
    //CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
    CGContextFillPath(ctx);
    CFRelease(mutatablepath);




    NSString *path0;
    NSArray *paths0=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    path0=[[paths0 objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"images"];
    NSError *error;

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:path0]) {

        if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager]createDirectoryAtPath:path0 withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error])

        {
            NSLog(@"Create directory error %@",error);

        }
    }




    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSData *imagedata=UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

    NSString *namepath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",@"test"];
    NSString *path;
    NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    path=[[paths objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"images"];
    NSString *savepath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",path,namepath ];


    // NSError 

    NSLog(@"%@",savepath);

    [imagedata writeToFile:savepath atomically:YES];


}
```

Comment: From the documentation for UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext:

You should call this function only when a bitmap-based graphics context is the current graphics context. If the current context is nil or was not created by a call to UIGraphicsBeginImageContext, this function returns nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so by taking the image saving code out of your `drawRect` method, since the `renderInContext` method implicitly calls `drawRect` as necessary:

```
UIView *myView = [[MyViewClass alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(/*...*/)];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myView.bounds.size);
[myView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Source: http://pastie.org/244916